# Unable to read vue file on reload

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs

I am using vue-pdf along with vue-server-renderer. While browsing the page internally, it works fine but on reload, webpack is unable to read .vue file in vue-pdf module.

```
vue-pdf/src/vuePdfNoSss.vue:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <style src="./annotationLayer.css"></style>
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function._load (/Users/aditya/rentomojo/node_module
```

Webpack config

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
```

EDIT:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Clone the [repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0).
2. npm install --save vue-pdf
3. Include it in any component.
4. Directly navigate to the route and it throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that *vue-pdf is not processed by vue-loader*

According to the official documentation of this library, there are an open bug for this exact behavior:

> Component is not processed by Webpack #13

with your exact error. You can check it in: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/13

You should either help to solve it or wait until it's solved.

Meanwhile you can try:

- **updating to v2** version of vue-pdf (it seems to work fine)
- check if you are rendering the pdf with only numbers (according to the documentation, with ONLY numbers it breaks).

**Alternative**

Since you have webpack, you might be better off installing pdfjs-dist into node modules (see pdfjs-dist), and removing it from where you have it now.

```
npm install pdfjs-dist
```

If you do this, the import is more 'standard',

```
import { PDFJS } from 'pdfjs-dist'
```

And try if this works fine.

(extracted from here: [Vue: use a custom libary (pdf.js) in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579229/vue-use-a-custom-libary-pdf-js-in-a-component))

Hope it helps or at least you have a point of reference.